# Switch virtual host to a new server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, virtualhost

I'm trying to migrate virtual hosts entries to a new server but pages are still being served from the old server.

What I've done on the new server:

1. I have created entries for the domain name in `sites-available` and created symlinks in `sites-enabled`. Conf file looks like this

   `<VirtualHost *:80>`

   ```
   ServerName domain_name:80
   ServerAdmin email@admin.com
   DocumentRoot "/home/domain/Sites"
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   ```

   `</VirtualHost>`
2. I have `NameVirtualHosts *:80` activated in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
3. I edited `/etc/hosts` to include `server_ip domain_name`

On the old server, the only thing I've done is to remove the VirtualHost entry for the site I'm trying to move over.

But I still get content from the old server.

I'm not sure if there are other things I need to do on the old server to properly migrate the virtual hosts to the new server.

Comment: Did you up date DNS/Load Balancer/Proxy to account for new server

Comment: By DNS is do you refer to editing this file `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: Depending on how you're resolving your host name, maybe? It could be the hosts file, it could be DNS zones located on internal servers, external servers or all of the above